# Django-Haystack - How to sort using get parameters?

Tags: django, django-haystack

I need to be able to sort data from the index like this:

```
http://mywebapp.com/search/?q=something&sort_by=points-desc
```

In other words, I need to pass the value of "sort_by" in the URL. I've trying to search on the documentation but I can't find any example.

Can someone give m a clue on how to achieve this?

I'm using Django Haystack 2.0 and the SearchView()

Any clues?

---

Update: Haystack Search Indexes

```
class LinkViewIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    section = indexes.CharField(model_attr='section')
    section_id = indexes.CharField(model_attr='section_id')
    item_author_username = indexes.CharField(model_attr='item_author_username')
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    url = indexes.CharField(model_attr='url')
    url_image = indexes.CharField(model_attr='url_image')
    comments = indexes.CharField(model_attr='comments', null=True)
    comments_count = indexes.CharField(model_attr='comments_count')
    points = indexes.CharField(model_attr='points')
    date_inserted = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='date_inserted')

    def get_model(self):
    return LinkView

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
    return self.get_model().objects.filter(date_inserted__lte=datetime.datetime.now())  


class TextViewIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    section = indexes.CharField(model_attr='section')
    section_id = indexes.CharField(model_attr='section_id')
    item_author_username = indexes.CharField(model_attr='item_author_username')
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    texto = indexes.CharField(model_attr='texto')
    comments = indexes.CharField(model_attr='comments', null=True)
    comments_count = indexes.CharField(model_attr='comments_count')
    points = indexes.CharField(model_attr='points')
    date_inserted = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='date_inserted')

    def get_model(self):
    return TextView

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
    return self.get_model().objects.filter(date_inserted__lte=datetime.datetime.now())  


class OffTopicLinkViewIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    section = indexes.CharField(model_attr='section')
    section_id = indexes.CharField(model_attr='section_id')
    item_author_username = indexes.CharField(model_attr='item_author_username')
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    url = indexes.CharField(model_attr='url')
    url_image = indexes.CharField(model_attr='url_image')
    comments = indexes.CharField(model_attr='comments', null=True)
    comments_count = indexes.CharField(model_attr='comments_count')
    points = indexes.CharField(model_attr='points')
    date_inserted = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='date_inserted')

    def get_model(self):
    return OffTopicLinkView

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
    return self.get_model().objects.filter(date_inserted__lte=datetime.datetime.now()) 


class OffTopicTextViewIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    section = indexes.CharField(model_attr='section')
    section_id = indexes.CharField(model_attr='section_id')
    item_author_username = indexes.CharField(model_attr='item_author_username')
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    texto = indexes.CharField(model_attr='texto')
    comments = indexes.CharField(model_attr='comments', null=True)
    comments_count = indexes.CharField(model_attr='comments_count')
    points = indexes.CharField(model_attr='points')
    date_inserted = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='date_inserted')

    def get_model(self):
    return OffTopicTextView

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
    return self.get_model().objects.filter(date_inserted__lte=datetime.datetime.now()) 


class BusinessLinkViewIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    section = indexes.CharField(model_attr='section')
    section_id = indexes.CharField(model_attr='section_id')
    item_author_username = indexes.CharField(model_attr='item_author_username')
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    country = indexes.CharField(model_attr='country')
    localidades = indexes.CharField(model_attr='localidades')
    url = indexes.CharField(model_attr='url')
    url_image = indexes.CharField(model_attr='url_image')
    comments = indexes.CharField(model_attr='comments', null=True)
    comments_count = indexes.CharField(model_attr='comments_count')
    points = indexes.CharField(model_attr='points')
    date_inserted = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='date_inserted')

    def get_model(self):
    return BusinessLinkView

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
    return self.get_model().objects.filter(date_inserted__lte=datetime.datetime.now()) 


class BicycleAdViewIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    section = indexes.CharField(model_attr='section')
    section_id = indexes.CharField(model_attr='section_id')
    item_author_username = indexes.CharField(model_attr='item_author_username')
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    country = indexes.CharField(model_attr='country')
    city = indexes.CharField(model_attr='city')
    n_item_kind = indexes.CharField(model_attr='n_item_kind')
    n_bicycle_ad_condition = indexes.CharField(model_attr='n_bicycle_ad_condition')
    bicyclead_link_url = indexes.CharField(model_attr='bicyclead_link_url', null=True)
    bicyclead_link_url_image = indexes.CharField(model_attr='bicyclead_link_url_image', null=True)
    bicyclead_insite_image = indexes.CharField(model_attr='bicyclead_insite_image', null=True)    
    texto = indexes.CharField(model_attr='texto', null=True)
    telephone = indexes.CharField(model_attr='telephone', null=True)
    price = indexes.CharField(model_attr='price', null=True)
    n_bicycle_ad_payment_type = indexes.CharField(model_attr='n_bicycle_ad_payment_type', null=True)
    propriedades = indexes.CharField(model_attr='propriedades', null=True)
    comments = indexes.CharField(model_attr='comments', null=True)
    comments_count = indexes.CharField(model_attr='comments_count')
    points = indexes.CharField(model_attr='points')
    date_inserted = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='date_inserted')

    def get_model(self):
    return BicycleAdView

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
    return self.get_model().objects.filter(date_inserted__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

The question should be. How can I pass the GET parameter to order by "points" or "date_inserted" using something like this:

```
http://mywebapp.com/search/?q=something&sort_by=points-desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Override get_queryset method of haystack and add your sorting fields to your index model, for example:

```
class LinkListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = “link”

    def get_queryset(self):
        sort = self.request.GET.get(‘sort_by’)
        if sort:
            return Link.published.filter().order_by('{0}'.format(sort))
        else:
            return Link.published.filter().order_by('-date_inserted')
```

Comment: Hi Catherina. Thanks for your reply. Can I query the Index instead of the Model?

Comment: I've included the indexes. I've also forgot to refer that I'm using ElasticSearch. Thanks